# How do I delete items from a dictionary while iterating over it?

Tags: python, dictionary

Can I delete items from a dictionary in Python while iterating over it?

I want to remove elements that don't meet a certain condition from the dictionary, instead of creating an entirely new dictionary. Is the following a good solution, or are there better ways?

```
for k, v in mydict.items():
    if k == val:
        del mydict[k]
```

Comment: A related question with very interesting answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9023078/custom-dict-that-allows-delete-during-iteration.

Comment: Dumb observation: Your whole loop is kind of pointless if you're just looking for a specific key. You could replace it with `try: del mydict[val]` `except KeyError: pass` or as a one-liner, with `mydict.pop(val, None)`, both of which would be `O(1)` operations, not `O(n)`. The question is still valid if the condition for deletion is more than just "equal to some value" though.

Comment: Many of the comments & answers here presume that this is impossible by definition - but it's not, it's just that Python doesn't provide an implementation.  For example in Java, it's possible to delete the most-recently iterated value of a `HashMap`  by using the iterator's `remove()` method.  This is highly desirable, because as all the examples here show, working around it is annoying, error-prone, and a waste of memory and time.

Answer (score 440, accepted):

For **Python 3+**:

```
>>> mydict
{'four': 4, 'three': 3, 'one': 1}

>>> for k in list(mydict.keys()):
...     if mydict[k] == 3:
...         del mydict[k]

>>> mydict
{'four': 4, 'one': 1}
```

The other answers work fine with **Python 2** but raise a `RuntimeError` for **Python 3**:

> RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration.

This happens because `mydict.keys()` returns an iterator not a list.
As pointed out in comments simply convert `mydict.keys()` to a list by `list(mydict.keys())` and it should work.

---

For **Python 2**:

A simple test in the console shows you cannot modify a dictionary while iterating over it:

```
>>> mydict = {'one': 1, 'two': 2, 'three': 3, 'four': 4}

>>> for k, v in mydict.iteritems():
...    if k == 'two':
...        del mydict[k]

------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython console>", line 1, in <module>
RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration
```

As stated in delnan's answer, deleting entries causes problems when the iterator tries to move onto the next entry. Instead, use the `keys()` method to get a list of the keys and work with that:

```
>>> for k in mydict.keys():
...    if k == 'two':
...        del mydict[k]

>>> mydict
{'four': 4, 'three': 3, 'one': 1}
```

If you need to delete based on the items value, use the `items()` method instead:

```
>>> for k, v in mydict.items():
...     if v == 3:
...         del mydict[k]

>>> mydict
{'four': 4, 'one': 1}
```

Comment: To elaborate on @max's elaboration, it will work if you convert the above code with 2to3.  One of the default fixers will make the loop look like `for k, v in list(mydict.items()):` which works fine in Python 3.  Same for `keys()` becoming `list(keys())`.

Comment: @TomášZato as Walter pointed out, for python3 you need to use `for k in list(mydict.keys()):`  as python3 makes the keys() method an iterator, and also disallows deleting dict items during iteration.  By adding a list() call you turn the keys() iterator into a list.  So when you are in the body of the for loop you are no longer iterating over the dictionary itself.

Comment: Will `list` make a copy of the keys, or only point at each of them?

Comment: @matanster `list` basically converts an `iterator` into a list of `keys`.

Comment: I would opt for `for key, value in my_dict.copy().items():` so you are iterating through a duplicate dictionary and deleting from the original. It maintains the cleanliness of the data typing

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6777485/modifying-a-python-dict-while-iterating-over-it
If the runtime error is removed there will a chance that you won't be able to iterate over all items

Comment: @xle You should make an answer out of your comment. It indeed seems to be cleaner.

Comment: can make it shorter `for k in list(mydict):`

Answer (score 118):

You could also do it in two steps:

```
remove = [k for k in mydict if k == val]
for k in remove: del mydict[k]
```

My favorite approach is usually to just make a new dict:

```
# Python 2.7 and 3.x
mydict = { k:v for k,v in mydict.items() if k!=val }
# before Python 2.7
mydict = dict((k,v) for k,v in mydict.iteritems() if k!=val)
```

Comment: @senderle: Since 2.7 actually.

Comment: The dict comprehension approach makes a copy of the dictionary; luckily the values at least don't get deep-copied, just linked. Still if you have a lot of keys, it could be bad. For that reason, I like the `remove` loop approach more.

Comment: You can also combine the steps: `for k in [k for k in mydict if k == val]: del mydict[k]`

Comment: the first solution is the only efficient one on big dicts in this thread so far - as it doesn't make a full length copy.

Answer (score 35):

Iterate over a copy instead, such as the one returned by `items()`:

```
for k, v in list(mydict.items()):
```

Comment: That doesn't make much sense -- then you can't `del v` directly, so you've made a copy of each v which you're never going to use and you have to access the items by key anyways. `dict.keys()` is a better choice.

Comment: @Josh: It all depends on how much you're going to need to use `v` as a criterion for deletion.

Comment: Under Python 3, `dict.items()` returns an iterator rather than a copy. See commentary for [Blair](https://stackoverflow.com/users/668807/blair)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5385075/2809027), which (sadly) also assumes Python 2 semantics.

Comment: Per python 3.11 this is the most correct answer but how can it bubble to the top.

Answer (score 27):

You can't modify a collection while iterating it. That way lies madness - most notably, if you were allowed to delete and deleted the current item, the iterator would have to move on (+1) and the next call to `next` would take you beyond that (+2), so you'd end up skipping one element (the one right behind the one you deleted). You have two options:

- Copy all keys (or values, or both, depending on what you need), then iterate over those. You can use `.keys()` et al for this (in Python 3, pass the resulting iterator to `list`). Could be highly wasteful space-wise though.
- Iterate over `mydict` as usual, saving the keys to delete in a seperate collection `to_delete`. When you're done iterating `mydict`, delete all items in `to_delete` from `mydict`. Saves some (depending on how many keys are deleted and how many stay) space over the first approach, but also requires a few more lines.

Comment: `You can't modify a collection while iterating it.` this is just correct for dicts and friends, but you can modify lists during iteration: `L = [1,2,None,4,5] <\n> for n,x in enumerate(L): <\n\t> if x is None: del L[n]`

Comment: @Nils It doesn't throw an exception but it's still incorrect. Observe: http://codepad.org/Yz7rjDVT -- see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/6260089/395760 for an explanation

Comment: Got me here. Still `can't` is correct only for dict and friends, while it should be `shouldn't` for lists.

Answer (score 14):

You can use a dictionary comprehension.

`d = {k:d[k] for k in d if d[k] != val}`

Comment: This is the most Pythonic.

Comment: But it creates a new dictionary instead of modifying `d` in place.

Answer (score 12):

With python3, iterate on dic.keys() will raise the dictionary size error. You can use this alternative way:

Tested with python3, it works fine and the Error "**dictionary changed size during iteration**" is not raised:

```
my_dic = { 1:10, 2:20, 3:30 }
# Is important here to cast because ".keys()" method returns a dict_keys object.
key_list = list( my_dic.keys() )

# Iterate on the list:
for k in key_list:
    print(key_list)
    print(my_dic)
    del( my_dic[k] )


print( my_dic )
# {}
```

Answer (score 12):

It's cleanest to use **`list(mydict)`**:

```
>>> mydict = {'one': 1, 'two': 2, 'three': 3, 'four': 4}
>>> for k in list(mydict):
...     if k == 'three':
...         del mydict[k]
... 
>>> mydict
{'four': 4, 'two': 2, 'one': 1}
```

This corresponds to a parallel structure for lists:

```
>>> mylist = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four']
>>> for k in list(mylist):                            # or mylist[:]
...     if k == 'three':
...         mylist.remove(k)
... 
>>> mylist
['one', 'two', 'four']
```

Both work in python2 and python3.

Comment: This isn't good in case your dataset is large. This is copying all the objects in memory, right?

Comment: @AFP_555 Yes - my goal here is for clean, parallel, pythonic code. If you need memory efficiency, the best approach I know of is to iterate and build either a list of keys to delete or a new dict of items to save. Beauty is my priority with Python; for large datasets I am using Go or Rust.

Answer (score 4):

You could first build a list of keys to delete, and then iterate over that list deleting them.

```
dict = {'one' : 1, 'two' : 2, 'three' : 3, 'four' : 4}
delete = []
for k,v in dict.items():
    if v%2 == 1:
        delete.append(k)
for i in delete:
    del dict[i]
```

Comment: Its rather a duplicate of @Ritzel's 1st solution (efficient on big dicts w/o full copy). Though a "long read" w/o list comprehension. Yet is it possibly faster nevertheless ?

Answer (score 3):

There is a way that may be suitable if the items you want to delete are always at the "beginning" of the dict iteration

```py
while mydict:
    key, value = next(iter(mydict.items()))
    if should_delete(key, value):
       del mydict[key]
    else:
       break
```

The "beginning" is only guaranteed to be consistent for certain Python versions/implementations. For example from [What’s New In Python 3.7](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.7.html)

> the insertion-order preservation nature of dict objects has been declared to be an official part of the Python language spec.

This way avoids a copy of the dict that a lot of the other answers suggest, at least in Python 3.

Answer (score 2):

I tried the above solutions in Python3 but this one seems to be the only one working for me when storing objects in a dict. Basically you make a copy of your dict() and iterate over that while deleting the entries in your original dictionary.

```
        tmpDict = realDict.copy()
        for key, value in tmpDict.items():
            if value:
                del(realDict[key])
```

Comment: Can also use `for key, value in my_dict.copy().items():` to be more succinct and avoid adding more variables to your scope than necessary

Answer (score 1):

One-liner:

```py
my_dict = {k: v for k, v in my_dict.copy().items() if not k == value}
```

The `my_dict.copy()` object is used for the iteration only and will not be available outside the scope of the dictionary comprehension. This avoids editing the object over which you are currently iterating, as advised against by [@user395760 in their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5384956/11950376).

You can split this over multiple lines for clarity:

```py
my_dict = {
    k: v
    for k, v in my_dict.copy().items()
    if not k == value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another nice and efficient way using partial function

```py
next((partial(d.pop, k) for k in d if k == v), partial(print, f"{v} key not found"))()
```

Comment: But hard to read and understand.