# Remove empty elements from nested JSON

Tags: json, python-3.x

I have a nested json with an **arbitrary depth level** :

```
json_list = [
    { 
        'class': 'Year 1', 
        'room': 'Yellow',
        'students': [
            {'name': 'James', 'sex': 'M', 'grades': {}},
        ]
    },
    { 
        'class': 'Year 2',
        'info': {
            'teachers': { 
                'math': 'Alan Turing', 
                'physics': []
            }
        },
        'students': [
            { 'name': 'Tony', 'sex': 'M', 'age': ''},
            { 'name': 'Jacqueline', 'sex': 'F' },
        ],
        'other': []
    }
]
```

I want to remove any element that its value meet certain criteria.

For example:

```
values_to_drop = ({}, (), [], '', ' ')
filtered_json = clean_json(json_list, values_to_drop)
filtered_json
```

*Expected Output of `clean_json`:*

```
[
    { 
        'class': 'Year 1', 
        'room': 'Yellow',
        'students': [
            {'name': 'James', 'sex': 'M'},
        ]
    },
    { 
        'class': 'Year 2',
        'info': {
            'teachers': { 
                'math': 'Alan Turing', 
            }
        },
        'students': [
            { 'name': 'Tony', 'sex': 'M'},
            { 'name': 'Jacqueline', 'sex': 'F'},
        ]
    }
]
```

I thought of something like first converting the object to string using `json.dumps` and then looking in the string and replacing each value that meets the criteria with some kind of flag to filter it after before reading it again with `json.loads` but I couldn't figure it out and I don't know if this is the way to go

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get the desired output by tweaking [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10179033/how-to-recursively-remove-certain-keys-from-a-multi-dimensionaldepth-not-known) a bit:

```
def clean_json(json_obj, values_to_drop):
    if isinstance(json_obj, dict):
        json_obj = {
            key: clean_json(value, values_to_drop) 
            for key, value in json_obj.items()
            if value not in values_to_drop}
    elif isinstance(json_obj, list):
        json_obj = [clean_json(item, values_to_drop)
                  for item in json_obj
                  if item not in values_to_drop]
    return json_obj
```