# How to remove large numbers of dictionary entries in python

Tags: python, regex, dictionary

I have a large dictionary in python(https://docs.google.com/document/d/1aNuwIJGRMQA2iSwdT2iliG9Q4Zu2bELNMrQVacEcSdc/edit?usp=sharing) and I want to remove all of the entries that have certain characteristics.For example, I want to remove all of the entries in which The second item in the tuple is equal to True, but the third is not equal to block.I was trying to do this with a regular expression, but I couldn't seem to get it working.

edit:My basic idea was to do something like this.

```
regex="Regular Expression"

for entry in d:
    if len(re.findall(regex,str(entry)))!=0:
        del d[entry]
print(d)
```

Comment: Does iterating not work?

Comment: Have you looked at `filter`?

Comment: When you say "it doesn't work", what exactly do you mean? Is it throwing an error, or just not producing desired results? It looks to me like one problem is that you are iterating over the dictionary while deleting from it.
You can fix this by changing `for entry in d:` to `for entry in d.keys():`, as mentioned in this answer:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/5385075/391161.

Comment: Definitely look up pandas. You can label these columns and your query will look something like `g[(not g.happy) & (g.action != 'block')]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think regular expressions is the way to go here, if your dictionary is actually in Python.

Here's a sample of your data:

```
g = {
(0, False, None, 0, False, None):(False,False,True),
(0, True, fire, 0, True, fire):(1/1,1/1,1/1),
(0, True, fire, 0, True, block):(1/1,1/1,1/1),
(0, True, fire, 0, True, reload):(1/1,1/1,1/1),
(0, True, fire, 0, False, fire):(1/1,1/1,1/1),
(0, True, fire, 0, False, block):(1/1,1/1,1/1),
(0, True, fire, 0, False, reload):(1/1,1/1,1/1),
(0, True, fire, 1, True, fire):(1/1,1/1,1/1),
(0, True, fire, 1, True, block):(1/1,1/1,1/1),
(0, True, block, 2, False, reload):(1/1,1/1,1/1),
(0, True, block, 3, True, fire):(1/1,1/1,1/1),
(0, True, block, 3, True, block):(1/1,1/1,1/1),
(0, True, block, 3, True, reload):(1/1,1/1,1/1),
(6, False, reload, 6, True, reload):(1/1,1/1,1/1),
(6, False, reload, 6, False, fire):(1/1,1/1,1/1),
(6, False, reload, 6, False, block):(1/1,1/1,1/1),
(6, False, reload, 6, False, reload):(1/1,1/1,1/1),
}
```

And so I would use the following, since list comprehensions and generator statements have virtually replaced map and filter in Python, now, and filtering for where the second element of the keys is `True` and the third element is not equal to `block`:

```
selected_keys = [i for i in g.keys() if i[1] == True and i[2] != block]
```

Then you can access the dict by each key you've filtered for.

For example:

```
for key in selected_keys:
    print(g[key])
```

would print the value associated with each key.

Answer (score 0):

```
def remove(key, value):
    return key[1] == True and key[2] != block

g = {key:value for key,value in g.iteritems() if not remove(key, value)}
```

Answer (score 0):

A very simple way of doing that would be.

```
for entry in d.keys():
    if entry[1]==True and entry[2]!=block:
        del d[entry]
```

In this case the loop for needs to read the keys() method, so the change on the dictionary size does not affect the loop.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Some basic text processing will get you a nice csv like this:

```
a,b,action1,c,d,action2,e,f,g,h,i,j
0,True,fire,0,True,fire,1,1,1,1,1,1
0,True,fire,0,True,block,1,1,1,1,1,1
0,True,fire,0,True,reload,1,1,1,1,1,1
0,True,fire,0,True,fire,1,1,1,1,1,1
0,True,fire,0,True,block,1,1,1,1,1,1
0,True,fire,0,True,reload,1,1,1,1,1,1
0,True,fire,1,True,fire,1,1,1,1,1,1
0,True,fire,1,True,block,1,1,1,1,1,1
0,True,fire,1,True,reload,1,1,1,1,1,1
0,True,fire,1,True,fire,1,1,1,1,1,1
```

This can be read in via `pandas.read_csv`. Obviously my column names are garbage. Once we have a dataframe, we can subdivide it by column values very easily. Your query is just `df[df.b & (df.action1 != 'block')`.