# How do I delete elements in dictionary in a for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I want to delete some items in a dictionary in a for loop, then I follow the codes from this [How to delete items from a dictionary while iterating over it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5384914/how-to-delete-items-from-a-dictionary-while-iterating-over-it)

Looping over `.keys`:

```
b = {'a':1, 'b' : 2}
for k in b.keys():
    if b[k] == 1:
        del b[k]
```

Results in:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration
b
{'b': 2}
```

Similarly, looping over `.items()`:

```
b = {'a':1, 'b' : 2}
for k, v in b.items():
    if v == 1:
        del b[k]

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration
b
{'b': 2}
```

After the loop, it returns the correct result, but `RuntimeError` is also raised, how can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You alter `d` with `del d[k]` so iterating over it's `.keys` or `.values` makes no difference, you alter the underlying iterator and so it complains.

You could either make a `list` of the `.keys`, with `list(b)`, or `.items`, with `list(b.items())`, essentially copying them to a new iterator that doesn't relate to the dictionary you're altering:

```
# list(b) would suffice instead of .keys
for k in list(b.keys()):
    if b[k] == 1:
        del b[k]
```

or, use a dict comprehension:

```
d = {k:b[k] for k in b if b[k] != 1}
```

to filter out unwanted elements.

Comment: `list`   is unnecessary too. for k in v would have worked the same.

Comment: What `v` are you referring to? @user312016

Comment: Oh, I missread your question, my example was bad, b instead of v: for k in b.

Comment: @user312016 `for k in b` doesn't do the trick here, you're still iterating over an iterator (implicitly `d.keys()`) that's connected to `b`, the `RuntimeError` still gets raised.

Comment: What I meant is for k in dict(b) would probably be more readable (assuming the dict is not too large, in which case that may impact performance).

Answer (score 2):

You can't remove elements in a `dict` while iterating over it.

The best way would be to use a `dict` comprehension:

```
b = {'a':1, 'b' : 2}
b = {k: v for k, v in b.items() if v != 1}
```

You could also make a copy of your `dict` while iterating over it:

```
b = {'a':1, 'b' : 2}
for k, v in dict(b).items():
    if v == 1:
        del b[k]
```

Here, you are iterating over a copy of `b` while modifying the original `b`, this is why it works: you are never removing elements from the copy.