# Unable to delete a dictionary key while iterating through another dictionary in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I am trying to delete a key from a dictionary while iterating through it. While directly trying to remove the key form the dictionary I was getting `RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration`. My code for that is.

```
mydict = {'one': 1, 'two': 2, 'three': 3, 'four': 4}

for k, v in mydict.items():
    if k == 'two':
        del(mydict[k])
        continue
    print(k)
```

To avoid this I copied the same dictionary to another dictionary and then I tried to remove the content from the copied dictionary while iterating the previous dictionary. But still, I am getting the error.

```
mydict = {'one': 1, 'two': 2, 'three': 3, 'four': 4}

new_dict = mydict
for k, v in mydict.items():
    if k == 'two':
        del(new_dict[k])
        continue
    print(k)
```

So can anyone please help to solve this issue.

Comment: Why would you iterate a dictionary simply to delete a specific key?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to delete items from a dictionary while iterating over it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5384914/how-to-delete-items-from-a-dictionary-while-iterating-over-it)

Comment: @Ribes & @jpp - My query is related the deletion of `new_dict` key. I was iterating `mydict` dictionary but unable to delete `new_dict` key.

Answer (score 2):

For Python-3-x the easy way is to convert the `dict` into a `list()` in the iteration:

```
mydict = {'one': 1, 'two': 2, 'three': 3, 'four': 4}

for k, v in list(mydict.items()):
    if k == 'two':
        del(mydict[k])
        continue   
    print(k)
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot delete a key-value pair while iterating the dictionary. Instead you can use a `dict comprehension`

**Ex:**

```
mydict = {'one': 1, 'two': 2, 'three': 3, 'four': 4}
print({k:v for k,v in mydict.items() if k != 'two'})
```

**Output:**

```
{'four': 4, 'three': 3, 'one': 1}
```

Comment: I was trying to delete the keys form the copied dictionary as I was not iterating that dictionary. Is python not allow to remove any dictionary key while iterating through a dictionary?

Comment: `new_dict = mydict` does not work the way you think it does. Python has a different mechanism. You need to read about copying objects in python.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the key in advance and wish to delete it from your dictionary:

- Do **not** try to delete it while iterating the dictionary.
- Do **not** copy the dictionary, iterate and delete.
- Do **not** create a list of tuples from the dictionary, iterate and delete.

Instead, just use `del mydict['two']`.

Usually, there is no reason why you need to delete a known key *while iterating*, especially since dictionaries are considered unordered and you cannot tell when you will reach the selected key.

Answer (score 0):

a simpler way is to make a shallow copy of the dict before iterating, like this:

```
t = "t"
mydict = dict()
mydict["1"] = "t";
mydict["2"] = "a"
print(mydict)
for key, value in mydict.copy().items():
    if value == t:
        del mydict[key]

print(trades)
```

Answer (score -1):

You're still getting error in second code, cause new_dict is just another variable referencing the same object. You can simply copy my_dict instead of making another variable pointing to it.

```
new_dict=my_dict.copy()
```

Sadly dict do not have deep copy method, so it have to be imported:

```
from copy import deepcopy
new_dict=deepcopy(my_dict)
```

For more info look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986006/how-do-i-pass-a-variable-by-reference).

Comment: In the case yes, but my_dict.copy() is shallow copy. If You want deep copy just "from copy import deepcopy" and then use deepcopy.