# Deleting Dictionaries Keys with a For If Statement in Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I feel very dumb asking this. How do I delete a keys in a dictionary with an if statement that references the values. When I do this:

```
newdict = {"a":1,"b":2,"c":3}

for (key,value) in newdict:
    if value == 2:
        del newdict[key]
print(newdict)
```

It throws this error:

```
line 3, in <module>
    for (key,value) in newdict:
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
```

Thank you.

Comment: `for k, v in newdict.items()`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Iterating over dictionaries using 'for' loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294889/iterating-over-dictionaries-using-for-loops)

Comment: When I add .items() I get RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration

Comment: Also, if I use a dictionary comprehension {del k:v for k,v in newdict.items() if v == 2}, it throws back "SyntaxError: invalid syntax" for del

Comment: Bizarre. Alright, thank you.

Comment: [How to delete items from a dictionary while iterating over it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5384914/how-to-delete-items-from-a-dictionary-while-iterating-over-it) - Updated link formatting

Comment: @AaronMazie you dont want to use a dictionary comprehension for side effects.  In your case, `{k: v for k, v in newdict.items() if v !=2 }`

Comment: Yeah, I didn't realize that wasn't pythonic. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to delete based on the items value, use the `items()` method or it'll give `ValueError`. But remember if you do so it'll give a `RuntimeError`. This happens because `newdict.items()` returns an iterator not a `list`. So, Convert `newdict.items()` to a `list` and it should work. Change a bit of above code like following -

```
for key,value in list(newdict.items()):
    if value == 2:
        del newdict[key]
```

output -

```
{'a': 1, 'c': 3}
```