# How to print and delete key if value of list has specific item from a stack

Tags: python

I have a `dict` inside a class. Trying to print, delete, 
    te.is_empty()    # Not printing anything
    te.printstats()   # not printing my stack. Nothing.

```
   for k,v in te.items():
      if v[0] == 'Available':
          print(k)
```

Can you help me?

Comment: Why do you call the dictionary a _stack_? Stack is a totally different data structure.

Comment: Your current class does not have an attribute `items`, yet it is called here: `for k,v in te.items():`. Did you mean `te.items.items()`?

Comment: @Ajax1234 : Yes, I made a mistake there. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few mistakes in your code, for example -

```
te.is_empty() # Not printing anything
```

Obviously, you are missing a `print` statement, do this -

```
print(te.is_empty())
```

And here -

```
for k,v in te.items():
```

I don't know why you are not getting an error here but it should be something like -

```
for k, v in te.items.items():
```

Why? Because your `instance` contains `items` that you need to `iterate` with python's `items` as in your `__init__`, it's a dict. So essentially, modify your code to -

```
# for k, v in te.items.iteritems(): # python2
for k, v in te.items.items(): #python3, this is what you need
    if "Available" in v:
        print(k)
```

And your prints should work

Comment: I see `te.printstats()` didn't work for me because of the missing prints.
For the second modification to print 'Available' tests, I still dont get output after copy/paste of your suggestion above.

Comment: Okay great, no problem @YouHaveaBigEgo

Comment: Can you also help me how to delete a key/list pair? if test say is `Test4`? Is my pop method correct in my class?

Comment: @YouHaveaBigEgo did you try the pop method? Did it remove the item? If not, we'll debug it

Comment: I get the error "RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration" When I try : for k, v in te.items.items():
        if v[0] == 'Running' and v[1] == 'Pending':
            print(k)
            te.remove(k)

Comment: How do I avoid this error , it still doesn't work for me. I changed my method back to self.items.pop(item) in my class

Comment: You'll need to build a temporary dictionary of items that you want to pop. After the iteration is done, you can pop. Refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5384914/how-to-delete-items-from-a-dictionary-while-iterating-over-it)

Comment: The solution in that link is for Python 2. How do I do on Python 3?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I 100% understand your question, but most of the problems you seem to be having are due to these issues in your code:

1. The is_empty() and printstats() calls don't print anything because you don't call the print() function. The two functions only *return* True/False and the stack's items respectively. If you intend to print these values, you'll need to surround the calls with print() functions.

> ```
> print(te.is_empty())
> ```

2. This isn't working because you're calling the te_stack object's items field as if it were a function. I think the confusion is happening here because te.items is a dictionary, which itself has an items() method, which returns the list of tuples I assume you want (basically). So, the line should read:

> ```
> for k, v in te.items.items():
> ```

3. With #1 in mind, I think this works as intended.

Comment: How do I edit a value inside my list? Say if my value for a test says it's 'Pending', I would like to modify it to 'Pass'

Comment: The way to do this with the way your code is currently written is:

`te.items['Test6'][1] = 'Pass'`

However, it might be beneficial for your to design a "Test" data structure that contains fields for running status and pass/fail status and methods to manipulate those.

Comment: @YouHaveaBigEgo I think first you'll need to get the key that you want to modify and write a small logic to modify it. Just use the for loop logic and loop over the list

Comment: Is the `remove` method in my class correct way to remove a key/value?

Comment: Yes, the dictionary's `pop()` method works (it did when I tested your code). Alternatively, you can do `del(self.items[arg])`. The difference is that `pop()` returns the deleted argument, `del()` does not.

Comment: It didnt for me. I did `if k == 'Running' and "Pending" in v:
            te.remove(k)`.I forgot to tell you that I added another record to my dict. with value `Pending`

Comment: @sgh304 : I can't directly access `self.items`. I did :
 `for k, v in te.items.items():
        if k == 'Running' and v[1] == 'Pending':
            te.remove(k)` . Remove isn't working still

Comment: @sgh304. Can you check if this remove method works?  def del_item(obj):
    for k, v in te.items.items():
        if k == 'Running' and v[1] == 'Pending':
            te.remove(k)

Comment: @sgh304: typo above. it should read v[0] == 'Running' and v[1] == 'Pending'. I get the error RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration