# RuntimeError: OrderedDict mutated during iteration (Python3)

Tags: python, python-3.x, iteration, ordereddictionary, mutated

Getting the error mentioned in the title. The below mentioned functioned is called by another function that is called through a POST api.

Error is on the line below the print statement. Don't know what the error means and why its coming. The same code used to run a week back.

```
def remove_individual_stops(ordered_parkstop_dict, relevant_data):
    new_ordered_parkstop_dict = ordered_parkstop_dict
    for key, value in ordered_parkstop_dict.items():
        if len(value) == 0:
            for k,v in ordered_parkstop_dict.items():
                if key in v:
                    new_ordered_parkstop_dict.pop(key)
        print (type(ordered_parkstop_dict), ordered_parkstop_dict)
        for k,v in ordered_parkstop_dict.items():
            klist = []
            keylist = []
            if value and v:
                if len(v)==1 and len(value)==1:
                    klist.append(k), keylist.append(key)
                if (keylist == v) and (klist == value and len(value) == 1):
                    new_ordered_parkstop_dict.pop(key)
    return new_ordered_parkstop_dict
```

Comment: you walk through the object and modify it at the same time.

Comment: [How to delete items from a dictionary while iterating over it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5384914/how-to-delete-items-from-a-dictionary-while-iterating-over-it) I think this is a very relevant answer, besides making a copy of the dictionary, as in the answer.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You assigned `new_ordered_parkstop_dict` with a reference of the `ordered_parkstop_dict` dict, so when you iterate over `ordered_parkstop_dict.items()` and mutate `new_ordered_parkstop_dict` by popping it, you mutate `ordered_parkstop_dict` too, which can't be done since your loop is iterating over `ordered_parkstop_dict`.

You should assign a copy of `ordered_parkstop_dict` to `new_ordered_parkstop_dict` instead. Change:

```
new_ordered_parkstop_dict = ordered_parkstop_dict
```

to:

```
new_ordered_parkstop_dict = ordered_parkstop_dict.copy()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. The issue is fixed but can you explain why did the error pop up now while the same code was working last week

Comment: The error does not necessarily occur because you're putting `new_ordered_parkstop_dict.pop(key)` in a conditional block, so with a different input it may or may not trigger the error by satisfying or not satisfying the condition.

Comment: Ok thats obvious, but what if i tell you that there is no change with the input as well. The same code is deployed in another server and it runs perfectly for the same input.

Comment: That's most likely because the other server is running Python 2.7 or earlier versions, where mutating a dict while iterating over it is allowed.

Comment: I had my doubt but didn't check what version of python was runnning. Sir, Thanks a lot for helping out.

Comment: You don't need any reputation to accept an answer. Try clicking on the grey check mark next to an answer to accept it. :-)

Comment: cool, there are very interesting comments above. I migrated my code from python 2.7 to python 3.7. I get the same error with an OrderedDict. Shouldn't I do `deepcopy` instead of `copy`?

Answer (score 0):

You should assign the copy object of `ordered_parkstop_dict` to `new_ordered_parkstop_dict` with [dict()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-dict) or [copy()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.copy) as shown below:

```py
new_ordered_parkstop_dict = dict(ordered_parkstop_dict)
```

```py
new_ordered_parkstop_dict = ordered_parkstop_dict.copy()
```

In addition, you can check if the objects are the same with [is](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#is) operator as shown below:

```py
person1 = {"name": "John", "age": 36}
person2 = person1
print(person1 is person2) # True
```

```py
person1 = {"name": "John", "age": 36}
person2 = dict(person1)
print(person1 is person2) # False
```

```py
person1 = {"name": "John", "age": 36}
person2 = person1.copy()
print(person1 is person2) # False
```