# Removing JSON key from file in python

Tags: python, json

I have a file with multiple JSON objects, like so:

```
[
  {
"fields": {
    "project": {
        "key": "GID"
    },
    "description": "",
    "documentKey": "AB-TC-678",
    "globalId": "GID-462256",
    "idb_metric": "framework.jama.infra.tagged.testcases",
    "lastActivityDate": "2017-12-19",
    "name": "Admin: Action commands",
    "sequence": "4.13.2.13.5.1.17",
    "testCaseStatus": "PASSED",
    "testCaseSteps": "FIELD_NOT_PRESENT"
   }
},
{
"fields": {
    "project": {
        "key": "GID"
    },
    "description": "",
    "documentKey": "AB-TC-679",
    "globalId": "GID-462256",
    "idb_metric": "framework.jama.infra.tagged.testcases",
    "lastActivityDate": "2017-12-19",
    "name": "Admin: Action not",
    "sequence": "4.13.2.13.5.1.18",
    "testCaseStatus": "PASSED",
    "testCaseSteps": "FIELD_NOT_PRESENT"
    }
}
]
```

What I'm trying to do is delete lines where key=x, for example, where key="idb_metric". Using answers/comments below (thanks!), I'm almost there:

```
if 'idb_metric' in element["fields"]:
    print("Found idb_metric!")
    del element['fields']['idb_metric']
    print(element)
```

But if I look for a second key by adding an elif, only the first key (in the first if block) is found/deleted:

```
elif 'sequence' in element["fields"]:
        print("Found sequence!")
        del element['fields']['sequence']
        print(element)
```

Expected results if I were to use the above code:

```
[
  {
"fields": {
    "project": {
        "key": "GID"
    },
    "description": "",
    "documentKey": "AB-TC-678",
    "globalId": "GID-462256",
    "lastActivityDate": "2017-12-19",
    "name": "Admin: Action commands",
    "testCaseStatus": "PASSED",
    "testCaseSteps": "FIELD_NOT_PRESENT"
   }
},
{
"fields": {
    "project": {
        "key": "GID"
    },
    "description": "",
    "documentKey": "AB-TC-679",
    "globalId": "GID-462256",
    "lastActivityDate": "2017-12-19",
    "name": "Admin: Action not",
    "testCaseStatus": "PASSED",
    "testCaseSteps": "FIELD_NOT_PRESENT"
    }
}
]
```

Comment: your `key` is nested in the dictionary object, you are expected to use nested dictionary calls: `element['fields']['idb_metric']`

Comment: as an FYI, be careful about deleting elements from a `dict` that you are iterating over. in this case it's ok, because the you aren't actually removing the elements over which you are iterating https://stackoverflow.com/a/5385075/5491375

Comment: [please limit to one question per post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222735/can-i-ask-only-one-question-per-post)

Comment: please include your desired output/result in the question?

Comment: @davedwards Added expected results. Also, I wouldn't say this is a second question as the original question was not satisfactorily answered. This is why I updated my comments for clarity.

Comment: To your second question, use another `if` rather than `elif`. The `elif` won't run if the the first `if` is satisfied.

Answer (score 2):

As one of the commenters mentioned, you aren't indexing into the correct field in your json dictionary.

To fix:

```
with open('input.json',encoding='utf8') as in_file:
    data = json.load(in_file)
    for element in data:
        del element["fields"]["idb_metric"]

    print(element["fields"])
```

It may also save you some headaches if you make sure that the key exists before trying to delete it. This is one way to check if it exists:

```
with open('input.json',encoding='utf8') as in_file:
    data = json.load(in_file)
    for element in data:
        if element.get("fields") is not None:
            if element["fields"].get("idb_metric") is not None:
                del element["fields"]["idb_metric"]
    print(element["fields"])
```

As an answer to your edited question, don't use elif:

```
if 'idb_metric' in element["fields"]:
    print("Found idb_metric!")
    del element['fields']['idb_metric']
    print(element)

if 'sequence' in element["fields"]:
    print("Found sequence!")
    del element['fields']['sequence']
    print(element)
```

Comment: You can simplify that check to `if 'idb_metric' in element["fields"]`

Comment: Thanks, that worked but then next question is how to find/delete multiple keys. Updated question accordingly.