# Delete key/value from a dictionary Json

Tags: python, json, dictionary, telebot

In a simple Telegram bot with Telebot I have a dictionary in json format (parole.json). I'm trying a function that allows me to delete an entry (key value pair) from the dictionary and I used this code example found right on this forum:

```
import json

with open("parole.json", "r") as json_file:
    Dizio = json.load(json_file)

@bot.message_handler(commands=['cut'])
def removeKey(message):
    parola = extract_arg(message.text.lower())

    res = Dizio.get(message.text.lower(), parola)
    trova = str(parola)

    with open("parole.json", "r") as f:
        data = json.load(f)

    if trova in data:
        del data[trova]

    with open("parole.json", "w") as f:
        json.dump(data, f)
```

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: The problem is that it doesn't delete the key-value pair. Executes the function but leaves the json file untouched.

Comment: But why are you opening the same file twice to read the json content into both Dizio and data?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Removing JSON key from file in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52979136/removing-json-key-from-file-in-python)

Comment: You're right, it's a useless step. But even taking it off doesn't work.

Comment: `del` itself indeed works fine, you can try `xy=json.loads('{"a":1,"b":2}');print(xy);del xy['a'];print(xy);print(json.dumps(xy))`. Your data and/or input are the culprits here.

Comment: ho to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52979136/removing-json-key-from-file-in-python)? It's basically the same question and the answer is already given.

You need to iterate over the keys by using a for loop that checks if the `input == ['key']['value']`

Also, your indenting is incorrect in your removekey(message) function:

```
def removeKey(message):
    parola = extract_arg(message.text.lower())
    res = Dizio.get(message.text.lower(), parola)
    trova = str(parola)

    with open("parole.json", "r") as f:
        data = json.load(f)

    if trova in data:
        del data[trova]

    with open("parole.json", "w") as f:
        json.dump(data, f)
```

Edit: I see that the indentation was edited just now

Comment: Ok. I solve it.
It was necessary to pass the element to be found in string format.
Once converted, it works.
Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

```
if trova in data:
    del data[trova]
```

Calling `dict.__del__` removes the `key`/`value` pair, so if your file is unchanged it's because the flow never enters the `if` statement.

---

Maybe it would work with

```
if trova in data.keys():
```

but I'm not sure if it makes any difference.

Comment: If I don't "transform" it into a string it gives me this error:
if parola in data.keys():
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Comment: trying I discovered this:
if I use

del data ['key']

everything works.
Therefore it fails to implement the if condition correctly.
How can I solve?