# how to fix " runtime error :dictionary changed size during iteration " in python 3.7

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, runtime-error

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':

    students = {}

    for _ in range(int(input())):
        name = input()
        score = float(input())
        seq = {name: score}
        students.update(seq)
        a = min(students, key=students.get)

    for key, value in students.items():
        while a == min(students, key=students.get):
            del students[min(students, key=students.get)]

    print(students)
```

In the above code, I would like to remove the minimum valued element in the dictionary.

I am able to remove a single minimum element from the dictionary. But I want to remove all such minimum valued elements if there are more than one same minimum valued elements in the dictionary.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to delete items from a dictionary while iterating over it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5384914/how-to-delete-items-from-a-dictionary-while-iterating-over-it)

Answer (score 0):

you can use `min` on `students.values()` to get the minimum value,

then collect all keys that have this same value,

then use `del` for all these keys, like this:

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':

    students = {}

    for _ in range(int(input())):
        name = input()
        score = float(input())
        seq = {name: score}
        students.update(seq)

    min_val = min(students.values())
    all_keys_with_min_val = [key for key, value in students.items() if value == min_val]

    for key in all_keys_with_min_val:
        del students[key]

    print(students)
```

Answer (score 0):

The most robust approach is not to remove entries, but to create a new `dict` without them. Use a `dict` comprehension to filter out all entries matching the lowest score:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    students = {}
    for _ in range(int(input())):
        name = input()
        score = float(input())
        students[name] = score  # store directly without update
    min_score = min(students.values())  # calculate minimum only once

    students = {
        name: score for name, score in students.items()
        if score != min_score  # only keep students above minimum score
    }
    print(students)
```

If you want to modify your initial `dict`, create a separate list of entries to iterate on:

```
...
min_score = min(students.values())  # calculate minimum only once

min_score_students = [name for name, score in students.items() if score == min_score]
for student in min_score_students:
    del students[key]
print(students)
```