# Unexpected behavior while modifying the dictionary in python

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, runtime-error, cpython, python-internals

I am trying to modify a dictionary object while iterating over it. But python will raise a `RuntimeError` saying that `dictionary changed size during iteration` to avoid unexpected behavior(this is expected).

```
>>> a = {1: 2, 2: 3}
>>> for key in a:
...     if key % 2 == 0:
...             a.pop(key)
...
3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration
```

But what actually surprised me is that even though the above code block exited with `RuntimeError` the dictionary `a` got modified.

```
>>> a
{1: 2}
```

Why is that?. Is this behavior is documented somewhere?.

Below is my python version and implementation.

```
>>> import sys, platform
>>> sys.version_info
sys.version_info(major=3, minor=8, micro=0, releaselevel='final', serial=0)
>>> platform.python_implementation()
'CPython'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the reason is because after popping the item, the `for` loop fails when trying to move on to the next key value. In other words, the error occurs after removing the key,value pair. See the answers [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5384914/how-to-delete-items-from-a-dictionary-while-iterating-over-it)

Comment: Yes, The `RuntimeError` is raised on the [`dictiter_iternextkey`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/ffd9753a944916ced659b2c77aebe66a6c9fbab5/Objects/dictobject.c#L3550). So only after the first mutation of the object, it can get to know that the object got changed. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score -1):

Probably is better to create a copy of the dict and have the `gc` do the rest.

```py
b = {k:v for k,v in a.items() if k%2 != 0}
```