# pyhton list - remove dictionares with certain key

Tags: python, list

When running this python code:

```
shapes = [{"label": "bad_stuff"}, {"label": "cat"}, {"label": "cat"},{"label": "cat"}, {"label": "bad_stuff"}, {"label": "bad_stuff"}]
for elem in shapes:
    if elem['label'] == "bad_stuff":
        shapes.remove(elem)
```

... I get this result:

```
[{'label': 'cat'}, {'label': 'cat'}, {'label': 'cat'}, {'label': 'bad_stuff'}]
```

Why does not the code remove the last element in the list and how can I solve it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5384914/how-do-i-delete-items-from-a-dictionary-while-iterating-over-it

Comment: @mont_ `shapes` is a list, not a dictionary.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove items from a list while iterating?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207406/how-to-remove-items-from-a-list-while-iterating)

Comment: @JohnnyMopp - it's the same issue.  If you modify the object you're iterating over you'll get weird things happening.

Comment: @TimTisdall Sure, I'm not arguing that point. It's just the link in mont_'s comment is specifically for dictionaries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are modifying list during for loop.
Let's see what's happening in your code:

On 1st interation it removes shapes[0] item.
2, 3, 4 iterations do not satisfy condition, so passed.
On 5th iteration the elem is `{"label": "bad_stuff"}`, and your shapes looks like this:

```
[{"label": "cat"}, {"label": "cat"},{"label": "cat"}, **{"label": "bad_stuff"}**, {"label": "bad_stuff"}]
```

So when you `remove(elem)` on this step, it removes last item in the list.
And since you removed last item - iteation stops.

There is solution to your problem:

```
shapes = [{"label": "bad_stuff"}, {"label": "cat"}, {"label": "cat"},{"label": "cat"}, {"label": "bad_stuff"}, {"label": "bad_stuff"}]

cat_shapes = []
for elem in shapes:
    if elem['label'] != "bad_stuff":
        cat_shapes.append(elem)
```

Another solution mentioned in comments by **DanielB**
:

```
cat_shapes = [elem for elem in shapes if elem['label'] != "bad_stuff"]
```

Comment: A [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) would also be a good solution here.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `filter`,

```
list(filter(lambda x:x['label'] != 'bad_stuff', shapes))
# [{'label': 'cat'}, {'label': 'cat'}, {'label': 'cat'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove matching elements from list please check below code

```
def remove_bad_stuff(shapes, remove_value):
    for elem in shapes:
        if elem['label'] == remove_value:
            shapes.remove(elem)
            remove_bad_stuff(shapes, remove_value)

shapes = [{"label": "bad_stuff"}, {"label": "cat"}, {"label": "cat"},{"label": "cat"}, {"label": "bad_stuff"}, {"label": "bad_stuff"}]
remove_bad_stuff(shapes,"bad_stuff")
print(shapes)
```