# How to remove a specific fox object from a dictionary while iterating through it

Tags: python, oop

I get a runtime error when i try to remove a fox object from a dictionary when it has starved in my simulation program, how can i fix this?

I tried to use other methods i discovered online, but i kept getting the same error.

```
import random

class Simulation:
    def __init__(self):
        self.Foxes = {}
        for i in range(100): # Creates 100 foxes
            self.Foxes[i] = Fox()

        def Main(self):
            for i in range(100): # Forages for each fox and checks for starvation
                for i in self.Foxes.keys(): 
                    self.Foxes[i].Forage()
                    if self.Foxes[i].Hunger >= self.Foxes[i].HungerMaximum:
                        self.Foxes.pop(i)

            print("There are " + str(len(self.Foxes)) + " foxes remaining.")

class Animal:
    def __init__(self): 
        self.Age = 0
        self.HungerMaximum = 50
        self.Hunger = 0
        self.ForagingChance = 20

    def Forage(self):
        if random.randint(1,self.ForagingChance) == self.ForagingChance:
            if self.Hunger > 10:
                self.Hunger = self.Hunger - 10
        else:
            self.Hunger = self.Hunger + 10
        
class Fox(Animal):
    def __init__(self):
        Animal.__init__(self)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Can you share the error you are getting please

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is a copy/paste error but your indentation is incorrect. Lines 10-16 under the `Main` function need to be indented. The entire `Main` function might also need to be unintended to be equal with the `__init__` function depending on how you want to use it.

```
class Simulation:
    def __init__(self):
        self.Foxes = {}
        for i in range(100): # Creates 100 foxes
            self.Foxes[i] = Fox()

    def Main(self):
        for i in range(100): # Forages for each fox and checks for starvation
            for i in self.Foxes.keys(): 
                self.Foxes[i].Forage()
                if self.Foxes[i].Hunger >= self.Foxes[i].HungerMaximum:
                    self.Foxes.pop(i)

            print("There are " + str(len(self.Foxes)) + " foxes remaining.")
```

As the other answer mentioned, you also are going to get a `RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration` due to modifying a dictionary while iterating over it.

Answer (score 0):

In these lines:

```
            for i in self.Foxes.keys(): 
                self.Foxes[i].Forage()
                if self.Foxes[i].Hunger >= self.Foxes[i].HungerMaximum:
                    self.Foxes.pop(i)
```

By calling `self.Foxes.pop(i)` within the for loop over `self.Foxes.keys()`, you are changing the size of the dictionary during iteration over the elements of the dictionary. This is not allowed in Python and will generate a `RuntimeError`.

To get around this limitation, create a new list containing `self.Foxes.keys()` -> `list(self.Foxes.keys())` and iterate over that:

```
            for i in list(self.Foxes.keys()): 
                self.Foxes[i].Forage()
                if self.Foxes[i].Hunger >= self.Foxes[i].HungerMaximum:
                    self.Foxes.pop(i)
```

See also the answers here: [How do I delete items from a dictionary while iterating over it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5384914/how-do-i-delete-items-from-a-dictionary-while-iterating-over-it)